# Mongodb doesn't insert item into collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb database called `interview_prac`. In `interview_prac` there is a collection called `Users`. When a user signs up the username and password are stored in this collection such as `{name:_username,password:_password}`.
I already inserted an item into `Users`. when I type `db.Users.find()` I get the following: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a22abd0321b10be42f82ac"), "name" : "reddit", "password" : "1234" }`

Now when a user signs up the new users name should be inserted into this collection, however it doesn't happen.

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/adduser', function (req, res, next) {
    var _username = req.body.username;
    var _password = req.body.password;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/interview_prac';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        //if we didn't connect, throw error
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("connected")

        var users = db.collection('Users')
            users.findOne({
                name: _username
            }, function (err, user) {
                if (user) {
                    err = 'The username already exists'
                        res.render('about', {
                            msg: err
                        })
                } else {
                    users.insert({
                        name: _username,
                        password: _password
                    }, function (err, result) {
                        console.log("entry saved")
                        var new_msg = "Welcome " + _username
                            res.render('about', {
                                msg: new_msg
                            })
                    })
                }
            })

            db.close()
    })
    console.log("Database closed")
})
```

Every time a new user signs up, the shows `entry saved` and closes the database, which means that the new user should be in my collection. However when I do `db.Users.find()`. I only get one user, there should be two. I can't seem to figure out why this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mongo`'s functions are asynchronous. You're closing the `db` connection before it has even done any of the code inside your `connect` callback.

Change your `db.close()` call inside the `insert`'s callback.

```
router.post('/adduser', function (req, res, next) {
    var _username = req.body.username;
    var _password = req.body.password;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/interview_prac';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        //if we didn't connect, throw error
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("connected")

        var users = db.collection('Users')
            users.findOne({
                name: _username
            }, function (err, user) {
                if (user) {
                    err = 'The username already exists'
                        res.render('about', {
                            msg: err
                        })
                } else {
                    users.insert({
                        name: _username,
                        password: _password
                    }, function (err, result) {
                        db.close()
                        console.log("Database closed")
                        console.log("entry saved")
                        var new_msg = "Welcome " + _username
                            res.render('about', {
                                msg: new_msg
                            })
                    })
                }
            })
    })
})
```